# No error in debug mode, wordpress template can not be loaded

Tags: custom-post-types, filesystem

I am trying to solve this issue for days.. I consumed all options and therefore need some fresh ideas.. I have a page template for posting/editing 2 different custom post types from front end of wordpress.

For the sake of simplicity, I will name these custom post types as post_type_x and post_type_y here. Names of the pages, at which these post types can be editted would be page_x and page_y respectively and both pages are assigned to use the same template. So, the code structure of the template page is below:

```
<?php
if (is_page('page_x')) {
    $current_post_type = "post_type_x";

    some if statements to determine the $action variable according to the $_POST variables

        switch ($action) {
            case "...":                 
            .... break;         
            case "update_save":
            .... break;
        }

}  elseif (is_page('page_y')) {
    $current_post_type = "post_type_y";

    some if statements to determine the $action variable according to the $_POST variables

        switch ($action) {
            case "...":                 
            .... break;         
            case "update_save":
            .... break;
        }

} else { ...
}
....
get_header(); ?>
....

<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" name="post_adv_resp_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
<input type="file" name="file-attachment" id="file-attachment" />
....
</form>
....
```

Under the "update_save" case there is such a code:

```
case "update_save":
$post_id = update_post_of_custom_type($_POST['post_id'],$post_title,$post_content,'draft');
if ($post_id != false) {
$file_upload = upload_file_of_custom_type($_FILES['file-attachment'],$post_id,'file-attachment');   
... 
} break;
```

The problem is: When I am testing on page_x, "update_save" case works perfectly. upload_file_of_custom_type function uploads the file, update the post meta. But, when I am on page_y, the script uploads the file and then breaks, does not update the post meta. And I have a white screen. Although the debug mode is on, no error shows on the screen. When I checked the apache logs, I found nothing..

```
function upload_file_of_custom_type($files,$post_id,$file_form_handler) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    ... some controls ...

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_form_handler, $post_id, array( 'test_form' => false ) ); $notice = "attach_id: ".$attach_id."upload is OK";                            
    if ($attach_id != false){                                      
        $file_load = update_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_attached_file',$attach_id);       
        if ($file_load == false) {
        $notice = __('An error occured while setting the post meta for the uploaded file.', TDOMAIN);
        } elseif ($file_load == true) {
            $notice = 'OK';
        }
    } else {
        $notice = __('An error occured while uploading the file.', TDOMAIN);
    }
return $notice;
}
```

One more information.. the post_type_y is posted as a sub page of post_type_y.. I don't know whether this makes any difference.. Are there any ideas about what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had given a rest to this problem and returned it back today with a fresh mind.. I noticed that the problem is about file upload function.. I revised the code as below:

```
$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_form_handler, $post_id );                         
if ($attach_id != false){ // if the attachment is loaded, register them as post meta
    $file_load = update_post_meta($attach_id,'_wp_attached_file',$files['name']);                                     
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, ABSPATH."media/".$files['name'] );
    $file_load = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    if ($file_load == false) {
        $notice = __('An error occured while setting the post meta for the uploaded file.', TDOMAIN);
    } elseif ($file_load == true) {
        $notice = 'OK';
    }
} else {
    $notice = __('An error occured while uploading the file.', TDOMAIN);
}
```